# Strong existence of solutions to SDE and continuity in the time variable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I recently come across some literature in stochastic analysis that uses the following result:

> Consider the one-dimensional SDE
>
> $$dX_t=  a(t, X_t) \, dt + b(t, X_t) \, dW_t, $$
>
> where $a, b: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are Borel-measurable functions and $\{W_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ is a Wiener process. Suppose that $a,b$ also satisfy
>
> $1. \, \, \,  \,\,\,\,\,|a(t,x)- a(t,y)| + |b(t,x) - b(t,y) | \leq K |x-y|, \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R},$ $\forall t \geq 0$, for some constant $K>0$, and
>
> $2. \, \, \,  \,\,\,\,\, $the functions $t \mapsto a(t,x)$ and $t \mapsto b(t,x)$ are continuous, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Then, the SDE has a unique strong solution.

The classical result about existence of strong solution in SDEs requires Lipschitzness in the space variable and linear growth in the space variable. I don't see how the latter can be replaced by the requirement of continuity in the time variable. Does anyone know the proof of this result?

Ref: At the bottom of Page 23 of https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/28918/3/McMurray-EFV-2015-PhD-Thesis.pdf

Comment: A *global* Lipschitz condition *implies* at most linear growth. Or did you perhaps mean "linear growth in the *time* variable"? That is never a problem, blowup can't be caused by weird phenomena in the time variable.

Comment: @Ian I don't understand.... These two things aren't correlated when we have time dependence, right?

Comment: @Ian https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/28918/3/McMurray-EFV-2015-PhD-Thesis.pdf 
Please have a look at the bottom of Page 23.....

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue from there either: a global Lipschitz condition in space (independent of both the current space value and time) gives at most linear growth in space, which gives uniqueness and prohibits blowup in finite time. Note that a *local* Lipschitz condition gives uniqueness but does not prohibit blowup in finite time.

Comment: @Ian If that is the case, then why do we need the continuity criterion to establish existence?

Comment: The continuity in time is necessary for basically the same reason as in the ODE case. But nothing *better* than continuity in time is required.

Comment: @Ian Sorry, I am still a bit unclear of why this is true. I haven't seen this result elsewhere. Do you mind telling me a source that contains a proof of this fact?

Comment: Wait, now I think I see the difficulty: if $b(x_0,t)$ or $\sigma(x_0,t)$ is not bounded in time then you may not have a universal constant for linear growth. Is that it?

Comment: If that's the problem, the trick is the usual local compactness trick: use the result you know to get the solution on any interval $[0,T]$.